# Running man copies of a program with redirection input and sleep

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sleep

I would like to do the follow

```
while read input
do echo "$input"
   sleep 1
done < input.txt | program $1 $2
```

But run many copies of the program in the background, I was thinking something with a for loop and an &, but that doesn't work well, anyone have know how?

Like so

```
for (( i=1; i<=3; i++ ))
do
while read input
do echo "$input"
   sleep 1
done < input.txt | program $1 $2 &
done
```

Or would it be better to have a different bash script call this bash script using &?

Comment: What doesn't work well?

Comment: It doesn't run in the each instance of the program in the background.

Comment: your 1st example will run ONE copy of program what read from the stdin one line/second. Your second example will do the same, only 3 times, so will run 3x program in the background and each program will read one line/second from the same input.txt. I don't understand why someone want run the same program with the same input 3 times. You probably want something different.

Comment: It's similar to that but there will be a different input[i].txt file for each copy of the running program, but all of has to happen in the back ground.

Comment: looks like it should work with `${input[i]}`, just be sure you understand the diff between ${input[i]}.txt` and `$input[$i]}.txt`, ect. If still not working, you'll have to give us something to better reconstruct your method (without posting your whole system). Good luck!

Comment: What want to do is make different input[$i].txt files, using a for loop. Then do the program loop with a the input[$i], all in parallel.

Comment: yes, seems like it should work.  Use `set -vx` to see how shell is expanding variable values. Good luck.